# What's the right way to access the data from a JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I have this object:

```
var Messages = {
    "msg100": "Message 100",
    "msg101": "Message 101",
    "msg102": "Message 102",
    "msg103": "Message 103",
}
```

If I want to get `msg101` I can do it using any of these two methods:

```
Messages.msg101
// or
Messages['msg101']
```

Both return the same value. So, what method is better to use and why?

Comment: You have an Object, not a "JSON Object".

Comment: Looks like I've forgot how google works. LOL. I've searched it and could not find a decent answer.

Answer (score -1):

The first one is more limited ( BTW i'm sure it's a dup).

```
var Messages = {

    "1": "Message 103"
}

alert(Messages.1) //nope
```

As opposed to this  :

```
var Messages = {

    "1": "Message 103"
}

alert(Messages["1"]) //all ok
```

Comment: This answer is a correct one. don't see any reason for downvote